# R weird {if-else} behaviour

Tags: r

I have the following if-else block and want to store its result in a variable.

```
x <- round(runif(100, -50, 50))
maxD <- 30
check1 <- T

y <- {
  if(x > 0 && !check1) pmax(pmin(x, maxD), 0) else if(x < 0 && check1) x else 0
}
```

Given that `check1 == T`, I'd expect `y` to be between `-50` and `0`, but the code doesn't seem to cut the values > 0. Why?

Also if I change `check1 = F`, then the output is a single value. But when I restart R and rerun the code (with `check1 = F`) I get a vector. When I change the value of `check1` again and then again, I suddenly get a single value. It is also often different after I restart R. This seems kinda arbitrary. What's happening here?

Comment: When you are checking for `x > 0` and you have 100 `x` values. What do you want that to mean? Do you want all `x` values above 0? At least 1? If you want to make a different decision for each, use `if_else()` and `&` rather than `if/else` and `&&`.

Comment: Also such problems are easier to identify and fix when you use fix set of numbers for debugging purposes whose output you know beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is a vector, but `&&` does't work with vectors. It will only evaluate the first element.

```
c(TRUE, FALSE) && TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

Given further that you generate `x` randomily with `runif` you will get a different result every time you run this code.